# Looping through Firestore is ignoring async await?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have an app where I have images stored on Firebase Storage and I want to loop through a few records in my Firestore and create Containers() for each of them to be used in a PageView. However, when looping through it seems like the AWAIT clues are ignored somehow?

This is what I got:

```
loadDashboard() async {
    // Load data about breed in focus
    Map<String, dynamic> _documentData;
    _isLoadingArticles = true;
    _dashboardArticles.clear();

    int _articleCount = 0;

    await _firestore
        .collection('DashboardArticle')
        .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        _articleCount++;

        downloadURL(doc["image"]);
        print(doc["title"]);

        _dashboardArticles.add(
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  child: Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      _articleImgUrl,
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 25),
                      Text(
                        doc["title"],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            shadows: [
                              Shadow(
                                blurRadius: 10.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                              ),
                            ],
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Text(
                        doc["tagline"],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          shadows: [
                            Shadow(
                              blurRadius: 10.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );

        setState(() {
          _isLoadingArticles = false;
          _totalArticleDots = _articleCount;
        });
       
      });
    }).catchError((e) => print("error fetching data: $e"));
  }

  Future<String> downloadURL(String image) async {
    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('dashboard_article_images/$image')
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((value) => {
              setState(() {
                _articleImgUrl = value;
                print(_articleImgUrl);
              })
            })
        .catchError((e) => {
              setState(() {
                _articleImgUrl = "";
              })
            });

    return "";
  }
```

_articleImgUrl is a variable outside that I set as I'm not sure how to get the String value from the Future in any other way.

Each PRINT shows the data in correct order, for example:

```
flutter: Pooch in focus: Corgi
flutter: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/.../o/article_images%2F4f3... (I truncated here)
```

When I se breakpoints it seems that _articleImgUrl has no value at the time the _dashboardArticles.add(...) is executed, so it feels like the awaits are skipped when looping somehow?

```
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///
```

Can anyone provide insights? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a quick example that would work in this context please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your `await` is ignored because you are not awaiting your method `downloadURL`, also I would not recommend to use `querySnapshot.docs.forEach` as you won't be able to manage asynchronous operations correctly. You should use `for in` instead, also you should not use `await` and `then` at the same time.

Here is some fix you could apply to your code:

```dart
final querySnapshot = await _firestore
  .collection('DashboardArticle')
  .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
  .get().catchError((e) => print("error fetching data: $e"));

for (final doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
  _articleCount++;
  await downloadURL(doc['image']);
  print(doc["title"]);

  // rest of your loop ...
}
```

By doing so you ensure all of your asynchronous operations are correctly awaited.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this: The type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.

Comment: Yes sorry, updated my answer, you should iterate on querySnapshot.docs in the for loop